# Invoking AsyncTask from an alert dialog in android

Tags: android, asynchronous, dialog, task, alert

I am trying to invoke a network laden task using `async task` in android.

Now the problem is that **I want a confirmation on click of a button,** say

- I want the user to ask if he really wants to fetch data from the
  network.
- On clicking a button the user is asked if he would want to proceed(This is done by an alert dialog).
- Now the async task's do in background and pre execute is called from
  a `alert dialog` yes confirmation.

Please suggest how do I do this, as the pre-execute is failing in my implementation.

Comment: Some code might help. Sounds a bit like you are calling doInBackground and preExecute directly, which you shouldn't do...

Answer (score 0):

Within the button click event, add a listener (Usually it will be a DialogInterface.OnClickListener()). A default onClick() function will be there. Call your Async task execute method inside the onClick(method).

If you have any error, kindly paste the LogCat message. That would help a lot.